# Photographing my mail and giving to my ex

Tags: criminal-law

My ex sent me a check for part of health insurance for children.  After it did not come, over 2 weeks, I reached out and told him I had not received the check.  He went to the post office, the mail clerks let him go through my mail and take a picture of the envelop that came from him.  It was conveniently on top of the pile, so he obviously went through it.  Sent it to me and told me it was at the post office.  Number 1, why was that not put in my box
Number 2 - why is anyone going through my mail
Number 3 - letting him take a photo?  That's not right.

Comment: Is this in the US, or some other country? Laws differ.

Comment: Check the postmark date. I wonder if he gave it to them or mailed that day or the previous day.

Comment: Also, did he tell you he went through your mail or did a clerk look through the mail, find the letter, and then let him take a photo?

Comment: it matters if he *opened* the letter, if you are divorced and in which country/state. IT might be a violation of the post office employee to let him go through your mail. Your complaint would be with the PO though.

Answer (score 3):

These all seem to be issues with how the local post office is handling your mail (and no doubt that of others). I would start by asking to see the person in charge of that office, and asking that person the same questions that you asked here.

I am not sure that, under US law, the "envelope information" of your mail is protected in the way that the contents are.